# Manipulating Soundcloud Stream with Chrome Extension Content Script

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

I am writing a Chrome extension using AngularJS to add functionality to the Soundcloud stream page.  I want to allow the user to create groups of artists so that they may only see a stream with tracks/shares/playlists from that group of artists.

For example, I follow 500 artists, but I want to quickly see a stream from my favorite 10 artists or from the artists I follow that are on the same label.

I am looking for advice on how I could go about making this as seamless as possible.  As of right now, my approach involves getting the tracks with the Soundcloud API and using angular's ng-repeat to display the tracks in a view injected into where the stream normally goes.  I realized using the Soundcloud widget was too slow and can't be customized to resemble the native stream items, so I copy/pasted the HTML that an actual stream item uses, but obviously the waveform/comment canvas and button functionality don't work.

What are my options as far as how I can approach this? Am I going to need to write my own players that look like the native Soundcloud ones? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [SoundCloud API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) which is very well documented.

If you have already the id's of the tracks / artist, you just have to request the url

**GET**
    http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/ID_OF_TRACK.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

to get all the informations you need about this track, like the `waveform_url`, and for the comments you was talking about :

**GET**
    http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/ID_OF_TRACK/comments.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

To reproduce the behaviour of the comments :

**POST** http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/ID_OF_TRACK/comments.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

(with a body param which represents the text and a timestamp in ms since the beginnin of the song, note that you must be connected)

If you don't have the id of the track, you could also use the `resolve` which give you all the info about a ressource if you have only the URL :

**GET**
    http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/poldoore/pete-rock-c-l-smooth-they&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Comment: I am already using the Soundcloud API.  I was curious about whether there are any tricks or good approaches I could use to implement playback without having to rewrite the players embedded in the stream and at the top of the page, since I'm writing this as a Chrome extension content script.

Comment: Yep, but don't think there's a better way since you have to add your custom controllers and behaviors, that's better to write your code instead of re-use something else :)